# html element memory storage capacity value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, memory

I wonder how can I get the memory capacity that a html element takes?

lets say that i have the next script...

```html
<body>
    <div id="id" class="class">some words</div>
    <textarea col="60" row="10"></textarea>
</body>
```

I want to find out in bytes or kb how much storage takes the textarea with users content and without?!?

In addition i want to find out how many kb or bytes the element itself takes?

Lets say that the div takes 0.0024kb as an element and + id + class + value takes 0.0154kb

Is there a way for me to find that out?

Thank you :)

Comment: if i understand the question i do not think you should have put the word "capacity" as the answers seem to be focusing on that. i think you are asking how you can find how much memory a particular element is currently using, which none of the answers seem to address

Answer (score 1):

In google chrome press f12, go to the profile tab.

Select the Take Heap Snapshot

Press take snapshot button

Then select in the many many choices HTML Document DOM tree

Then its up to you to select what item you wish to examine.

Comment: Didn't find what i searched for..... or i found and didn't know that it was it...... after i check an element with inspector i searched properties of the element.... yeah i saw all the million attributes it has but none of them shows me the storage capacity of the element

Comment: ... An element does not have a max storage capacity. When you drill down in the **heap snapshot** you get to see the memory size in bytes. its up you to divide by 1024 to get kilobytes. Did you follow all the steps I wrote down?

Comment: search Document DOM tree

Answer (score 0):

the max length of input field.

> The maximum number of characters allowed in the  element. Default value is 524288

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: Yeah but i need the storage capacity of any element?!? does all elements take the 524288 bytes storage capacity? and as i see it that this the max..... what if i need the current?

Comment: AFAIK there is no limit as a program.ofc You do have a physical limit(RAM/HDD) though